# All-cap abbreviations lead to undefined control sequence when used chapters/sections of books

Tags: glossaries-extra

I wanted to compile an old document on a new PC, so basically I switched from texlive 2021 to an up-to-date version of texlive 2023 for the compilation of a longer document (includes `glossaries-extra` among many other packages). This lead to the following error, which I have reproduced in a quite small example. But I have no idea what to do about it....

I use `glossaries-extra` for abbreviations (and other stuff).  At some point in the document, I want to access only small cap versions, capitalized versions, or all cap versions. The following code uses the three macros `\glsfmtname`, `\Glsfmtname`, and `\GLSfmtname` to do that. The use of the last one gives an error when `\GLSfmtname` tries to use the macro `\GLSxtrtitlename`. But not always, only under two conditions, as far as I can tell: 1) The document class has to be e.g. book or scrbook (I also tried article and didn't observe it). 2) There has to be at least one `\chapter`or `\section` or similar in the document, otherwise it compiles just fine.

```
\documentclass{book} % also for scrbook
%\documentclass{article} % NOT for article! (has no chapter, but same behavior for book+\section)
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\newabbreviation{xxx}{asa}{a simple abbreviation}

\begin{document}
%\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section} % uncomment for error


\gls{xxx}

\glsfmtname{xxx} 

\Glsfmtname{xxx} 

\GLSfmtname{xxx}  % <- error: \GLSxtrtitlename undefined

\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>  \GLSxtrtitlename
> {xxx}
> l.14 \GLSfmtname{xxx}
>
> ?

Did I miss some setting? Or can this be a bug?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can reproduce. This screams bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'll write a bug report then. :) A temporary fix would still be welcome if it's not too much effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`glossaries-extra`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) stores certain definitions before `\markboth` and `\markright` to prevent case-changing from being applied in headings when `\glsfmt<field>` is used in `\section` (see "5.3. Entries in Sectioning Titles, Headers, Captions and Contents" for more information).
Unfortunately that saving and restoring macros forgets to save a couple of definitions, this is why sectioning commands and `book` rather than `article` are required to demonstrate the bug in a minimal fashion.

The issue is in `\glsxtrmarkhook`, which only stores the `\glsxtrtitlename` and `\Glsxtrtitlename` macros (not `\GLSxtrtitlename`) to be restored later by `\glsxtrrestoremarkhook`, instead `\glsxtrrestoremarkhook` ends up trying to restore `\GLSxtrtitlename` by setting it equal to an undefined `\@glsxtr@org@GLSxtrtitlename`.

This can be patched (along with `\GLSfmtfirst` which is affected in the same way due to `\GLSxtrtitlefirst` not being saved) with

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\newabbreviation{xxx}{asa}{a simple abbreviation}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\glsxtrmarkhook{%
  \let\@glsxtr@org@GLSxtrtitlename\GLSxtrtitlename
  \let\@glsxtr@org@GLSxtrtitlefirst\GLSxtrtitlefirst
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}

\gls{xxx}

\glsfmtname{xxx} 

\Glsfmtname{xxx} 

\GLSfmtname{xxx}

\GLSfmtfirst{xxx}

\end{document}
```

There is also be a related issue with `\GLSfmtlong` and `\GLSfmtlongpl` when used in sectioning commands (where the User Guide suggests they would be supported), as `\GLSxtrtitlelong` and `\GLSxtrtitlelongpl` are neither saved by `\glsxtrmarkhook` nor restored by `\glsxtrrestoremarkhook`.

This can be patched as

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\newabbreviation{xxx}{asa}{a simple abbreviation}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\glsxtrmarkhook{%
  \let\@glsxtr@org@GLSxtrtitlelong\GLSxtrtitlelong
  \let\@glsxtr@org@GLSxtrtitlelongpl\GLSxtrtitlelongpl
  \let\GLSxtrtitlelong\GLSxtrheadlong
  \let\GLSxtrtitlelongpl\GLSxtrheadlongpl
}{}{}
\apptocmd\glsxtrrestoremarkhook{%
  \let\GLSxtrtitlelong\@glsxtr@org@GLSxtrtitlelong
  \let\GLSxtrtitlelongpl\@glsxtr@org@GLSxtrtitlelongpl
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section \GLSfmtlong{xxx}}

\gls{xxx}

\GLSfmtlong{xxx}

\end{document}
```